# Sorting datagridview c# - Additional information: DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

This is code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadermouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
DataGridViewColumn newColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = dataGridView1.SortedColumn;
ListSortDirection direction;

// If oldColumn is null, then the DataGridView is not sorted.
if (oldColumn != null)
{
    // Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder.
    if (oldColumn == newColumn &&
        dataGridView1.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else
    {
        // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        oldColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
    }
}
else
{
    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
}

// Sort the selected column.
dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);
newColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
    direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
    SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
}

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Put each of the columns into programmatic sort mode.
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
    }
}
```

Please can you tell me why when I run this code, occurs this error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted.

Comment: Is it runtime error or build error? Which line of code gives you error?

Comment: Show or tell us about if & how the DGV is data-bound!! - Wild guess: Did you turn off AllowUserToAddRows ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it's a runtime error, this line gives error: 
     dataGridView1.Sort(newColumn, direction);

Comment: @TaW no, i don't turn off AllowUserToAddRows, how do i do it?

Comment: It is a DGV property. When it is on there will be an empty row at the bottom and since ill its values are null sorting often crashes (unless the null cases are coded as well..)

Comment: @TaW i put AllowUserToAddRows = false, but error is still there. In some fields, i don't have nothing written, can it be problem? Is that reason why sorting crashes?

Comment: Could be, can you test it by setting the values at least to ""?